# Cypress type('fixture'), can I use type() with a fixture? for login

Tags: cypress

Trying to use cy.type() to fill an input, but i need to call data from the fixture file (JSON), and as I know, this action can only accept a string or number.

```
cy.get(main_page.UserName_element).type(userdata.userName)
```

My intention was to type the user name on the login input, by using the action: type(json_file.element) without hardcoding

full code:

```
 let userdata;
 before( ()=>{
     cy.fixture('login_ddt').then((ddt_data)=> {
         userdata = ddt_data;
     })
 })

    beforeEach("Visit the web main page", () => {
       cy.opening_main_URL() // this is cy.visit("web page")
    })

    it("User uses incorrect credentials and tries to login", ()=> {
       cy.get(main_page.UserName_element).type(userdata.userName)
    })
})
```

I have this error message "cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined"

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the fixture in the actual test. The code as written should work in some circumstances, but if `cy.opening_main_URL()` resets the browser (you would see it go blank then redraw), you will lose the `userdata` variable.

Do it this way instead, the `cy.fixture()` will cache the results. It behaves just like `before()` - it will only read the file once.

```js
beforeEach("Visit the web main page", () => {
  cy.opening_main_URL()
})

it('User uses incorrect credentials and tries to login', () => {
  cy.fixture('login_ddt').then(userdata => {
    cy.get(main_page.UserName_element).type(userdata.userName)
  })
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the issue remains "cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined". Can't find any example on the docs of using type with fixtures

Comment: LOL, well now it's obvious the problem occurs in your fixture file not your code.